# How to pass travis environment variables to docker run in script

Tags: docker, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I have a db password saved in my travis env. I want to pass this password in my docker run command in my `cd-deploy.sh` script. Is this possible? This is what I have now:

```
docker run -e password=$PASSWORD img_name
```

$PASSWORD is of course the env variable saved in travis. But this command doesn't work, first of fall is it possible to pass a travis env variable in a bash script? And if so, how do we properly do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `-e PASSWORD='$PASSWORD'`

Comment: single quotes will prevent variable expansion.

Comment: Guys, I made it work, by passing the env variable from travis.yml to deploy-cd.sh, I will post my answer later today

Answer (score 0):

In `.travis.yml`

```
./deploy-cd.sh $PASSWORD
```

In `deploy-cd.sh`

```
docker run -e password=$1 img_name
```

`$1` is the argument passed to the bash script, in this case `$1` is the value of `$PASSWORD` which is stored as environment variable in Travis